# Can´t use intent to move data to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, methods, crash

This is my first activity and whenever i try to pass the doubles "latitude and longitude" using Intent  my app crashes, I do not know what else to do.

I saw that if i dont put the startActivity(Intent) ii wont crash.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //
    requestPermission();
    //
    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.getLocation);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        return;
                    }

                client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.location);
                            textView.setText(location.toString());


                        }
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();


                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Lat",latitude);
                    intent.putExtra("Lon",longitude);
                    startActivity(intent);

                     }


                });
        }
    });
```

This is the another activity

hope it helps to find the error, i do not know why that line can cause so much toruble

thank you in advaced

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

public static final String FILENAME = "filename";

private ArrayList<Entity> selectedSat;

String fileName;
MenuItem favItem;




private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

private Frame earthFixedFrame;
private OneAxisEllipsoid earth;
protected GeodeticPoint pointPlot = null;
protected Marker currentMarker = null;
protected Polyline line = null;
protected Polyline pastLine = null;
public static final int PATTERN_DASH_LENGTH_PX = 20;
public static final int PATTERN_GAP_LENGTH_PX = 20;
public static final PatternItem DOT = new Dot();
public static final PatternItem DASH = new Dash(PATTERN_DASH_LENGTH_PX);
public static final PatternItem GAP = new Gap(PATTERN_GAP_LENGTH_PX);
public static final List<PatternItem> PATTERN_POLYGON_ALPHA = Arrays.asList(GAP, DASH);
protected ArrayList<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();

boolean initial = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    Drawable fav = getDrawable(R.drawable.favoritesicon);
    fav.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    selectedSat = SatelliteSelectActivity.getSelectedSat(); //Pulls a list of selected satellites from the previous activity
    System.out.println(selectedSat.get(0).getName());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        ab.setTitle(selectedSat.get(0).getName().trim());
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    fileName = getIntent().getStringExtra(FILENAME);

    int i = 0;

    System.out.println(selectedSat.get(i).getName());   //Prints Entity Name to the Console

    try {
        System.out.println("Velocidad:");
        System.out.println(selectedSat.get(i).getVelocity());       //Prints the velocity of the entity
    } catch (OrekitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onBackPressed() {       //Runs when you exit the activity
    selectedSat.clear();            //Clears the satellite list
    System.out.println("Terminar con el mapa");        //Prints to the console that we are done with the Maps activity
    initial = false;                //Boolean variable specifying we are dealing with the first satellite
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SatelliteSelectActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();                  //Closes the activity
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     //Creates action bar in the MapsActivity UI

    MenuInflater item = getMenuInflater();     //Specifies the item fit
    item.inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);   //Fits the menu to the item fit
    setTitle("SatFun");                  //Sets the action bar title
    favItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_fav);
    checkifFavorite(); // see if sat is favorite
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       //Called when icon in the action bar is selected

    switch (item.getItemId()) {


        case R.id.actionbar_fav:
            selectedSat = SatelliteSelectActivity.getSelectedSat();
            String fileName = getIntent().getStringExtra(FILENAME);

            if (!Favorites.contains(selectedSat.get(0).getName(), fileName, getApplicationContext())) {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.favoritesicon_filled);
                for (int i = 0; i < selectedSat.size(); i++)
                    try {
                        Favorites.addFavorite(selectedSat.get(i).getName(), selectedSat.get(i).getLine1(), selectedSat.get(i).getLine2(), fileName, getApplicationContext());
                        return true;
                    } catch (OrekitException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            } else {
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.favoritesicon);
                for (int i = 0; i < selectedSat.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        boolean removed = Favorites.removeFavorite(selectedSat.get(i).getName(), selectedSat.get(i).getLine1(), selectedSat.get(i).getLine2(), fileName, getApplicationContext());
                        System.out.print(removed);
                    } catch (OrekitException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

        case R.id.actionbar_info:
            ConstraintLayout satInfo = findViewById(R.id.satelliteInfo);
            if (satInfo.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                satInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                satInfo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    mapUpdater(getCreatedTime());

}

private int incr = 0;


public void mapUpdater(Date date) {

    if (date == null) {
        dateTime = getCreatedTime();
    } else {
        dateTime = date;
    }

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Nueva");
            while (incr++ < 1000) {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                updateMap();
                            } catch (OrekitException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();

}

private void setPastLine(AbsoluteDate date, double satPeriod) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> plotPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
        int period = (int) Math.round(satPeriod);
        int periodMin = (period / 100);
        System.out.println("DATE: " + date);
        pointPlot = updatePosition(date, 0);
        System.out.println("FRAGMENT (width, height): " + findViewById(R.id.map).getWidth() + "   " + findViewById(R.id.map).getHeight());
        double longitude = pointPlot.getLongitude() * 180 / Math.PI;
        double latitude = pointPlot.getLatitude() * 180 / Math.PI;

        //Creates map objects
        LatLng point_a = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        MarkerOptions point = new MarkerOptions().position(point_a);

        plotPoints.add(point_a);
        date = new AbsoluteDate(date, -periodMin);
    }

    pastLine = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(plotPoints));
    pastLine.setWidth(5);//Sets width of polyline
    pastLine.setPattern(PATTERN_POLYGON_ALPHA);
    pastLine.setColor(Color.RED);
}

private Date getCreatedTime() {  //Creates a new date with the current time and returns it
    return new Date();
}

private Date dateTime = null;



private void updateMap() throws OrekitException {

    System.out.println("Entering update map");
    if (dateTime == null) {
        dateTime = getCreatedTime();
    }
    AbsoluteDate date;

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedSat.size(); i++) {

        double satNum = selectedSat.get(i).getSatNum();
        TextView satNumberText = findViewById(R.id.satelliteNumber);







        String satelliteNumberString = "Número De Satelite: " + Math.round(satNum);
        satNumberText.setText(satelliteNumberString);


        TimeScale utc = TimeScalesFactory.getUTC();




        ArrayList<LatLng> plotPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

        double satPeriod = selectedSat.get(i).getPeriod();
        int period = (int) Math.round(satPeriod);
        int periodMin = (period / 100);
        System.out.println("Interval: " + periodMin);
        calendar.setTime(dateTime);

        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        date = new AbsoluteDate(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), utc); //creates orekit absolute date from calender

        this.initializeFrames();

        pointPlot = updatePosition(date, 0);

        String velocityString = df.format(selectedSat.get(i).getVelocity() * 3.6);

        velocityString = "Velocidad: " + velocityString + "km/h";

        TextView satVelocity = findViewById(R.id.velocity);
        satVelocity.setText(velocityString);


        //Finds longitude
        double longitude = pointPlot.getLongitude() * 180 / Math.PI;
        String longitudeString = "Longitud: " + df.format(longitude);
        TextView satLongitude = findViewById(R.id.satLongitude);
        satLongitude.setText(longitudeString);


        //Finds latitude
        double latitude = pointPlot.getLatitude() * 180 / Math.PI;
        String latitudeString = "Latitud: " + df.format(latitude);
        TextView satLatitude = findViewById(R.id.satLatitude);
        satLatitude.setText(latitudeString);


        double altitude = pointPlot.getAltitude() / 1000;
        TextView satAltitude = findViewById(R.id.satAltitude);
        String altitudeString = "Altitud: " + df.format(altitude) + "km";
        satAltitude.setText(altitudeString);



        //CALCULOS
        double longi= 78.5082717;
        double lati=0.245496;
        double delta1 = Math.abs(longitude);
        double delta = Math.abs(delta1-longi);

        double elev=Math.atan(((Math.cos(lati)*Math.cos(delta))-(6378/42164))/Math.sin(Math.acos(Math.cos(lati)*Math.cos(delta))));
        double az1 = Math.tan(Math.toDegrees(delta));
        double az2 = Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(lati));
        double az3 = Math.toDegrees(az1/az2);
        double az = Math.abs(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(az3)));

        double dis1 = (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lati)));
        double dis2 = (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(delta)));
        double dis3 = (dis1*dis2);
        double dis4 = (1-dis3);
        double dis5 = (0.41999*dis4);
        double dis6 = (1+dis5);
        double dis = (35786.04*(Math.sqrt(dis6)));




        TextView satdelta = findViewById(R.id.satdelta);
        String deltaString = "Delta: " + df.format(delta);
        satdelta.setText(deltaString);

        TextView azimuts = findViewById(R.id.azimut);
        String AzimutString = "Azimut: " + df.format(az);
        azimuts.setText(AzimutString);

        TextView disf = findViewById(R.id.distancia);
        String disString = "Distancia: " + df.format(dis) + "Km";
        disf.setText(disString);




        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



        System.out.println("Latitud: " + latitude);
        System.out.println("Longitud: " + longitude);
        System.out.println("PERIODO: " + periodMin);




        for (int k = 0; k < 300; k++) {

            System.out.println("DATE: " + date);
            pointPlot = updatePosition(date, i);
            System.out.println("FRAGMENT (width, height): " + findViewById(R.id.map).getWidth() + "   " + findViewById(R.id.map).getHeight());
            longitude = pointPlot.getLongitude() * 180 / Math.PI;
            latitude = pointPlot.getLatitude() * 180 / Math.PI;

            //Creates map objects
            LatLng point_a = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            MarkerOptions pointA = new MarkerOptions().position(point_a);

            if (k == 0) {
                if(currentMarker != null) {
                    currentMarker.remove();
                }
                if(line != null) {
                    line.remove();
                }
                if(pastLine != null) {
                    pastLine.remove();
                }
             }
                pointA.title(selectedSat.get(i).getName().trim() + "Poscicion Actual");
                if (initial) {
                    initial = false;
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point_a));
                }
            }
            plotPoints.add(point_a);
            date = new AbsoluteDate(date, periodMin);
        }
        date = new AbsoluteDate(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND), utc); //creates orekit absolute date from calender
        setPastLine(date, satPeriod);

        line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(plotPoints));
        line.setWidth(5);
        line.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
}

    private void initializeFrames() {

    try {
        Frame f;
        f = CelestialBodyFactory.getEarth().getBodyOrientedFrame();

        earthFixedFrame = FramesFactory.getTEME();

        earth = new OneAxisEllipsoid(
                Constants.WGS84_EARTH_EQUATORIAL_RADIUS,
                Constants.WGS84_EARTH_FLATTENING,
                f);
    } catch (OrekitException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private GeodeticPoint updatePosition(AbsoluteDate date, int i) {
    GeodeticPoint point = null;

    SpacecraftState scs = selectedSat.get(i).updateState(date);
    System.out.println(scs);
    System.out.println(scs.getPVCoordinates().getPosition());
    System.out.println(scs.getDate());
    System.out.println(earthFixedFrame);

    try {
        point = earth.transform(selectedSat.get(i).getVector(date), earthFixedFrame, date);
    } catch (OrekitException e) {
        System.out.println("Fallo al realizar la conversion cartesiana");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return point;
}


private void checkifFavorite() {

    if (fileName.contains("favorites_")) {
        fileName = fileName.replace("favorites_", "");
    }


    File test1 = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "favorites_" + fileName);


    if (test1.exists()) {
        System.out.println("file exists");
        try {
            ArrayList<String> favs = celestrakData.getNames("favorites_" + fileName, this);


            if (favs.contains(selectedSat.get(0).getName())) {
                System.out.println("already is a favorite");
                favItem.setIcon(R.drawable.favoritesicon_filled);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("file doesnt exist");
    }


}
```

}

Comment: What's the error you are getting from your logs

Comment: imgur.com/XhHQTW9 im having this one

Comment: The issue is not with the class you have posted in this question but rather in MapsActivity.class, the class you are calling. Can you also post the code for that class here

Comment: ok i´ll do that right now

Comment: it´s done, sorry i did not knew how to edit the post again

Comment: on line 104 of the MapsActivity please ensure your selectedSat list isnt empty before fetching or referencing items by index

Comment: i was triying to solve this, but everything works just fine before the startActivity(intent)

Comment: Yes, your logs say your app is crashing when you open MapsActivity and it  does so because of an outofrange exception. To debug try replacing MapsActivity with another class in your intent method and see of it opens

Comment: damn it works,by changing to another class it no longer crashes, thank you man!!!

Comment: Hey, i made it but now all the data i want to pass turns to cero.

Comment: Hey i made that, but im having a problem, are you still there or can i contact you throught another service?

Answer (score -1):

instead of using getApplicationContext() at your intent, Can you pls try passing the context of the Activity you are in.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivityName.this, MapsActivity.class);
```

hope it helps!

Also, it would be good if you can share the crash, too. It helps you to elaborate on your problem.

Comment: Can you pls share what crash you are getting?

Comment: When i click the button to get my latitude and longitude the app close by it self.

Comment: But you should be able to see smthng at your Logcat or Run section

Comment: it's too long to post on a coment im going to upload a .jpg of it. https://imgur.com/XhHQTW9

Comment: the error you get is about your MapsActivity, you are getting out of bound exception, probably you are doing smthng with array/arraylist  at 104.line of MapsActivity, but the array/arraylist you want to get smthng, has zero length. It means it has nothing, it looks that is your problem.